# Session Variable Value Undefined

Tags: php, session

I'm getting undefined session value while running!

create.php

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once('class_post.php');
$post=new Post();
$postid=$post->createPost();
$_SESSION["post_id"]=$postid;
echo $_SESSION["post_id"];
?>
```

*Output :* **142**

---

test.php

```
<?php
session_start();
print_r($_SESSION);
?>
```

*Output :* **Array ( [post_id] => undefined )**

Comment: which php version? and can you also show your createPost() method?

Comment: PHP Version : 7.2.7

`public function createPost(){
$create_post_statement = "INSERT INTO post(user_id,created_on, status) VALUES (?,NOW(),?)";

$sql_result = $this->db->query($create_post_statement,$this->user,'Draft');


return $this->db->getInsertedId();
}`

Answer (score 0):

PHP doesn't have a `undefined` keyword, so i suppose it comes from JavaScript for example. If the variable is not set, it will return `NULL` and trigger a php notice.

So i would rather check all my JavaScript code.

Comment: Yes! I'm executing **create.php** code using _javascript_ **XMLHttpRequest**.
Is there any way to set Session Variable ?